# How to insert multiple documents at once in MongoDB through Java

Tags: java, mongodb, bulkinsert, mongodb-java

I am using MongoDB in my application and  was needed to insert multiple documents inside a MongoDB collection .
The version I am using is of 1.6

I saw an example here

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/create/

in the

**Bulk Insert Multiple Documents**  Section

Where the author was passing an array to do this .

When I tried the same , but why it isn't allowing , and please tell me how can I insert multiple documents at once ??

```
package com;

import java.util.Date;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
            DB db = mongo.getDB("at");
            DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("people");

            /*
             * BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
             * document.put("name", "mkyong"); document.put("age", 30);
             * document.put("createdDate", new Date()); table.insert(document);
             */

            String[] myStringArray = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };

            collection.insert(myStringArray); // Compilation error at this line saying that "The method insert(DBObject...) in the type DBCollection is not applicable for the arguments (String[])"

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Please let me know what is the way so that I can insert multiple documents at once through java .

Comment: You can take a look at my response in another thread.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470702/bulk-upsert-with-mongodb-java-3-0-driver/39356860#39356860

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`DBCollection.insert` accepts a parameter of type `DBObject`, `List<DBObject>` or an array of `DBObject`s for inserting multiple documents at once. You are passing in a string array.

You must manually populate documents(`DBObject`s), insert them to a `List<DBObject>` or an array of `DBObject`s and eventually `insert` them.

```
DBObject document1 = new BasicDBObject();
document1.put("name", "Kiran");
document1.put("age", 20);

DBObject document2 = new BasicDBObject();
document2.put("name", "John");

List<DBObject> documents = new ArrayList<>();
documents.add(document1);
documents.add(document2);
collection.insert(documents);
```

The above snippet is essentially the same as the command you would issue in the MongoDB shell:

```
db.people.insert( [ {name: "Kiran", age: 20}, {name: "John"} ]);
```

Comment: thanks , is there any other way of doing this , i guess creating too many DBObject  will be probmalitic as i need to create nearly 100 .so is there any other way for this ??

Comment: I am not sure of other ways, but using Spring Data's [MongoOperations.insert()](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.1.0.M1/api/), you can get rid of the `DBObject` creation part(Spring does it for you).

Comment: How we can do this through Spring Data Mongo API's ?  Thanks, Deepa

Answer (score 24):

Before 3.0, you can use below code in Java

```
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("yourDB");
            DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("yourCollection");
            BulkWriteOperation builder = coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
            for(DBObject doc :yourList)
            {
                builder.insert(doc);
            }
            BulkWriteResult result = builder.execute();
            return result.isAcknowledged();
```

If you are using **mongodb version 3.0** , you can use

```
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("yourDB");
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("yourCollection");
            collection.insertMany(yourDocumentList);
```

Answer (score 18):

As of MongoDB 2.6 and 2.12 version of the driver you can also now do a [bulk insert operation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/).  In Java you could use the [BulkWriteOperation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/com/mongodb/BulkWriteOperation.html).  An example use of this could be:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("user");
BulkWriteOperation bulk = coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
bulk.find(new BasicDBObject("z", 1)).upsert().update(new BasicDBObject("$inc", new BasicDBObject("y", -1)));
bulk.find(new BasicDBObject("z", 1)).upsert().update(new BasicDBObject("$inc", new BasicDBObject("y", -1)));
bulk.execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

## Creating Documents

There're two principal commands for creating documents in MongoDB:

- `insertOne()`
- `insertMany()`

There're other ways as well such as `Update` commands. We call these operations, upserts. Upserts occurs when there're no documents that match the **selector** used to identify documents.

Although MongoDB inserts ID by it's own, We can manually insert custom IDs as well by specifying `_id` parameter in the `insert...()` functions.

To insert multiple documents we can use `insertMany()` - which takes an array of documents as parameter. When executed, it returns multiple `id`s for each document in the array. To drop the collection, use `drop()` command. Sometimes, when doing bulk inserts - we may insert duplicate values. Specifically, if we try to insert duplicate `_id`s, we'll get the `duplicate key error`:

```
db.startup.insertMany(
  [
  {_id:"id1", name:"Uber"},
  {_id:"id2", name:"Airbnb"},
  {_id:"id1", name:"Uber"},
  ]
  );
```

[image: MongoDB duplicate key error]

MongoDB stops inserting operation, if it encounters an error, to supress that - we can supply `ordered:false` parameter. Ex:

```
db.startup.insertMany(
[
{_id:"id1", name:"Uber"},
{_id:"id2", name:"Airbnb"},
{_id:"id1", name:"Airbnb"},
],
{ordered: false}
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your insert record format like in MongoDB that query retire from any source
EG.

```
 {
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : a
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : b,
}
```

it is **mongodb 3.0**

```
FindIterable<Document> resulutlist = collection.find(query);            
List docList = new ArrayList();
for (Document document : resulutlist) {
    docList.add(document);
}

if(!docList.isEmpty()){
    collectionCube.insertMany(docList);
}
```

Comment: what if by performing this it is giving "message='E11000 duplicate key error collection:". How to resolve this?