# How can I override ObjectId generator in mongo driver to generate custom objectId?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongoid

We can generate ObjectId from client and use it while insert. I done want it to be handled outside of insertion process. I need it to be configured as my default _id generation process so that when ever I call insert, insert method should create the custom objectId and use it. Is it possible with mongodb's Java driver?

I need to somehow override the default _id generation process. I don't like to explicitly define _id in the inserting document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: insert documents with specific id instead of auto generated ObjectID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273821/mongodb-insert-documents-with-specific-id-instead-of-auto-generated-objectid)

Comment: @dnickless I have gone thorough that question before posting this here. That explains add custom _id by explicitly defining in the document. I don't like to explicitly define in the document. I want to override default _id generation process so that even if there is no _id defined in inserting document, it will create a new _id using the override _id generator.

Answer (score 1):

That is currently not possible directly through the driver.

Despite the fact that there is an IdGenerator interface in place which could be used to create a custom implementation there is currently no way to inject that custom instance into the driver.

You can see that in the MongoDB Java Driver [repository](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=IdGenerator&type=).

There was a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2200) to support this which, however, got closed as a duplicate of [another ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2457) which again is closed as "Won't fix".

You should be able, though, to implement your repository in a way that it assigns a custom id before saving anything.