# What's the difference between replaceOne() and updateOne() in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, crud

MongoDB bulk operations have two options:

1. [**`Bulk.find.updateOne()`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.updateOne/)

   > Adds a single document update operation to a bulk operations list. The operation can either replace an existing document or update specific fields in an existing document.
2. [**`Bulk.find.replaceOne()`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.replaceOne/)

   > Adds a single document replacement operation to a bulk operations list. Use the `Bulk.find()` method to specify the condition that determines which document to replace. The `Bulk.find.replaceOne()` method limits the replacement to a single document.

According to the documentation, both of these two methods can replace a matching document. Do I understand correctly, that `updateOne()` is more general purpose method, which can either replace the document exactly like `replaceOne()` does, or just update its specific fields?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

With `replaceOne()` you can only replace the entire document, while `updateOne()` allows for updating fields.

Since `replaceOne()` replaces the entire document - fields in the old document not contained in the new will be lost. With `updateOne()` new fields can be added without losing the fields in the old document.

For example if you have the following document:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("0123456789abcdef01234567"),
   "my_test_key3" : 3333
}
```

Using:

```
replaceOne({"_id" : ObjectId("0123456789abcdef01234567")}, { "my_test_key4" : 4})
```

results in:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("0123456789abcdef01234567"),
   "my_test_key4" : 4.0
}
```

Using:

```
updateOne({"_id" : ObjectId("0123456789abcdef01234567")}, {$set: { "my_test_key4" : 4}})
```

results in:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("0123456789abcdef01234567"),
   "my_test_key3" : 3333.0,
   "my_test_key4" : 4.0
}
```

Note that with `updateOne()` you can use the [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) on documents.

Comment: what do you mean with "change the schema"?

Comment: replace replaces a document with a new one, using the same parameters. with update you can add/remove parameters which make up the document.

Comment: ah ok, so replace always change `_id`

Comment: Hi, I just tried it with the current version of the c# driver 2.4.4. @caub: replace doesn't change the `_id`. @Hughzi: I was able to replace a document with more and with less fields. So what did you mean with "change the schema"?

Comment: @BooFar oh sorry yes, I was totally wrong, .replace(One) overwrites the whole document with the new one provided, but keeps _id. so it changes potentially the number of fields in that document. Usually you can use .updateOne and $set to keep existing values

Comment: After a little bit of experimentation, I can see that neither `updateOne()` or `replaceOne()` changes `_id` and either one can change the schema (the properties of the document). As far as I can tell, when using the same filter and a update / replacement document that contains all the desired properties, there's no difference between `updateOne(<filter>, {$set: <document>}` and replaceOne(<filter>, <document>).

Answer (score 21):

`replaceOne()` replaces the entire document, while `updateOne()` allows for updating or adding fields. When using `updateOne()` you also have access to the [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) which can reliably perform updates on documents. For example two clients can "simultaneously" increment a value on the same field in the same document and both increments will be captured, while with a replace the one may overwrite the other potentially losing one of the increments.

Since `replaceOne()` replaces the entire document - fields in the old document not contained in the new will be lost. With `updateOne()` new fields can be added without losing the fields in the old document.

For example if you have the following document:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("0123456789abcdef01234567"),

   "my_test_key3" : 3333
}
```

Using:

```
replaceOne({"_id" : ObjectId("0123456789abcdef01234567")}, { "my_test_key4" : 4})
```

results in:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("0123456789abcdef01234567"),
   "my_test_key4" : 4.0
}
```

Using:

```
updateOne({"_id" : ObjectId("0123456789abcdef01234567")}, {$set: { "my_test_key4" : 4}})
```

results in:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("0123456789abcdef01234567"),
   "my_test_key3" : 3333.0,
   "my_test_key4" : 4.0
}
```

Answer (score -5):

`db.collection.replaceOne()` does exactly the same thing as `db.collection.updateOne()`.

The main difference is that `db.collection.replaceOne()`'s data that are being edited will have to go back and forth to the server, whereas `db.collection.UpdateOne()` will request only the filtered ones and not the whole document!