# MongoDB (Java): efficient update of multiple documents to different(!) values

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a MongoDB database and the program I'm writing is meant to change the values of a single field for all documents in a collection. Now if I want them all to change to a single value, like the string value "mask", then I know that `updateMany` does the trick and it's quite efficient.

However, what I want is an efficient solution for updating to *different* new values, in fact I want to pick the new value for the field in question for each document from a list, e.g. an ArrayList. But then something like this

```
collection.updateMany(new BasicDBObject(), 
new BasicDBObject("$set",new BasicDBObject(fieldName, 
       listOfMasks.get(random.nextInt(size)))));
```

wouldn't work since `updateMany` doesn't recompute the value that the field should be set to, it just computes what the argument

```
listOfMasks.get(random.nextInt(size))
```

would be once and then it uses that for all the documents. So I don't think there's a solution to this problem that can actually employ `updateMany` since it's simply not versatile enough.

But I was wondering if anyone has any ideas for at least making it faster than simply iterating through all the documents and each time do `updateOne` where it updates to a new value from the ArrayList (in a random order but that's just a detail), like below?

````
// Loop until the MongoCursor is empty (until the search is complete)
        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {

                // Pick a random mask
                String mask = listOfMasks.get(random.nextInt(size));

                // Update this document
                collection.updateOne(cursor.next(), Updates.set("test_field", mask));

            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }```
````

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB provides the [bulk write API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846474/how-to-perform-a-bulk-update-of-documents-in-mongodb-with-java) to batch updates. This would be appropriate for your example of setting the value of a field to a random value (determined on the client) for each document.

Alternatively if there is a pattern to the changes needed you could potentially use [find and modify operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) with the available [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1).

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm really concerned about is time efficiency, and BulkWrite wouldn't help with that unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: Bulk write API batches changes to a single request, so it would reduce network round-trips which is a time cost.

Comment: Thanks! We'll look into it more