# C# Mongodb query documents by multiple fields in bulk

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following collection in the DB:

```
[123, 1]
[123, 3]
[456, 1]
[456, 2]
[456, 3]
```

And I have an array:

```
[123, 2]
[456, 4]
[456, 2]
```

I want to check what items in the array are in the DB. Using this example, the result should be:

```
[456, 2]
```

Is there any way to do this in Mongodb in bulk, meaning only 1 query instead of looping?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maby this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128490/how-to-insert-multiple-documents-at-once-in-mongodb-through-java

Comment: A collection can't just hold arrays, what do the documents actually look like?

Comment: @Radinator Thanks for your help, although I dont you how that post helps, can you explain further?

Comment: @johnnyHK Thanks for your help. The document is literally an { byte[], string } where byte[] is a hash and string is some sort of id for something else.