# insertMany dynamic query in mongodb function

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to save a document in `mongoDB database`. However I am not able to achieve this.

Below is my Code-

```
db.system.js.save({ _id:"createMultipleUsers", value:
    function() { 
        try {
            var query="";
            for(var i=0;i<2;i++ ) { 
                if(i !=0) {
                    query=query+",";  
                }
                query=query+"{ _id: "+i+", mobileNumber: "+i+", emailID: \"email"+i+"@gmail.com\"}";
            } 
            query="[ "+query+" ]";
           //print(query);
           db.User.insertMany(query);
       } catch (e) {
           print (e);
       }
   } 
});
```

Any help/hint is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I can see in your `db.system.js.save`, you are passing a string value to `insertMany` how ever its **recommended to pass JSON document** instead-

**Example-**

```
try {
   db.products.insertMany( [
      { item: "card", qty: 15 },
      { item: "envelope", qty: 20 },
      { item: "stamps" , qty: 30 }
   ] );
} catch (e) {
   print (e);
}
```

**Source-** https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#examples

**Similar Question-** [How to insert multiple documents at once in MongoDB through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128490/how-to-insert-multiple-documents-at-once-in-mongodb-through-java)

**In your Case-**

Insert query after converting into JSON Dictionary/Document-

```
//parse string query into json format.
db.User.insertMany(JSON.parse(query));
```

**Hoping this will help you :)**

Feel free to shoot your queries.

Comment: db.system.js.save({ _id:"createMultipleUsers", value:
    function() { 
        try {
            var query="";
            for(var i=0;i<2;i++ ) { 
                if(i !=0) {
                    query=query+",";  
                }
                query=query+"{ _id: "+i+", mobileNumber: "+i+", emailID: \"email"+i+"@gmail.com\"}";
            } 
            query="[ "+query+" ]";
           print(query);
           db.User.insertMany(JSON.parse(query));
       } catch (e) {
           print (e);
       }
   } 
});

Comment: ------------------------
But i am getting output as below
[ { _id: 0, mobileNumber: 0, emailID: "email0@gmail.com"},{ _id: 1, mobileNumber: 1, emailID: "email1@gmail.com"} ]
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data

Comment: if json structure is not proper then we get this error.. I am glad you corrected it...

Answer (score 0):

```
db.system.js.save({ _id:"createMultipleUsers", value:
    function() { 
        try {
            var query="";
            for(var i=0;i<2;i++ ) { 
                if(i !=0) {
                    query=query+",";  
                }
                query=query+"{ \"_id\": "+i+", \"mobileNumber\": "+i+", \"emailID\": \"email"+i+"@gmail.com\"}";
            } 
            query="[ "+query+" ]";
           print(query);
           db.User.insertMany(JSON.parse(query));
       } catch (e) {
           print (e);
       }
   } 
});
```

Comment: Hi Vikash Pandey Thanks for your help

Comment: Output :
------------
[ { "_id": 0, "mobileNumber": 0, "emailID": "email0@gmail.com"},{ "_id": 1, "mobileNumber": 1, "emailID": "email1@gmail.com"} ]

Its inserting data to db also

The errors for the question asked is resolved by 2 lines changes as below

Comment: The errors for the question asked is resolved by 2 lines changes as below

Comment: 1. query=query+"{ _id: "+i+", mobileNumber: "+i+", emailID: \"email"+i+"@gmail.com\"}";  TO  query=query+"{ \"_id\": "+i+", \"mobileNumber\": "+i+", \"emailID\": \"email"+i+"@gmail.com\"}";

Comment: 2. db.User.insertMany(query);  TO db.User.insertMany(JSON.parse(query));

Comment: glad to help :). if my ans was useful for you then accept it :)

Comment: yeah it means you had to insert a proper json instead of string.. correct?